# How to mock methods of wild class

Tags: java, junit, powermock

How to mock methods of wild class
For example, I have created the following method:

```
protected Object cloneBean(Object bean, Class<?> inClazz, Map<Object, Object> cloned) throws ClonerException {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = inClazz;
        Object clone = clazz.newInstance();
        cloned.put(bean, clone);
        while (clazz != null && !clazz.isInterface() && clazz != Object.class) {
            cloneFields(bean, clone, clazz, cloned);
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        }
        return clone;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ClonerException(e);
    }
}
```

I want to mock return ‘some object’ with getSuperClass() method. How to do it?

Comment: What's a "wild class"?

Comment: You should probably also add some more context. Runnable code would be the best. What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: You are not trying to mock a wild class you are trying to mock java.lang.Class of unknown type i.e. a wildcard. I dont think it is possible to mock java.lang.Class using mockito.

Comment: @cID, I think so too..